# CSS and JS are working on localhost, but not on Heroku Webserver

Tags: javascript, php, css, heroku, composer-php

Guys I've been working on a web platform and I had some issues deploying to heroku server. My CSS and JS files don't load, although the files were uploaded to heroku.

I'm using PHP7 and Bootstrap 4.0. I already verified the paths of the CSS and JS links.I actually use a php include to link my head.php to my main file (index.php). Here is the code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS First Try with the "relative" path used on heroku-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- General CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main_style.css">
<!-- Fav Icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="assets/imgs/favicon-32x32.png">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS Second Try with the "absolute" path used on heroku-->`enter code here`
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://whispering-waters.herokuapp.com/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- General CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://whispering-waters.herokuapp.com/assets/css/main_style.css">
<!-- Fav Icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://whispering-waters.herokuapp.com/assets/imgs/favicon-32x32.png">


<!-- Bootstrap CSS Third Try with CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- General CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://whispering-waters-50467.herokuapp.com/assets/css/main_style.css">
<!-- Fav Icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://whispering-waters-50467.herokuapp.com/assets/imgs/favicon-32x32.png">
```

I was expecting that any of this would fix the CSS and JS loading on Heroku. I'm accepting any suggestion. My thanks in advance

Comment: Is the app/page live to be checked ?

Comment: Well, you have `href="<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://...` at one point; that can't be right. Also, the text `enter code here` causes the rest of the links to be in the body; you may want to look into that.

Comment: So do you see it when you view the page source? What do you see in the network panel in your console?

Comment: And things like `https://whispering-waters.herokuapp.com/vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` don't exist; you get a 404 there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. First of all, I checked if the page is live, this doesn't seem to be the problem. @Mr Lister, I'm sorry but as it was my first question here I may have pasted it the wrong way, sorry about that. I will post the right code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. The problem was the composer package management. I fixed the project composer dependencies and it started working. 
I realized this problem could occur with NodeJs npm and other package manager as well. If someone is facing the same problem, it is worth a try verifying your package dependencies.

My sincerely thanks for the support.